# Java : Timer executing before the time of command

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I want to execute foo() at a particular time. Here is my code:

```
public void scheduler() throws ParseException {
    java.util.Timer _timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask tt;
    tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            foo();
        }
    };
    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    java.util.Date date = dateFormatter.parse("14:26:00");
    _timer.schedule(tt,date);
}

public void foo(){
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

But foo() is actually getting executed when I run the code itself, and not at the specified time. Please help

Comment: Have a look at the value of `date` as a string.

Comment: Yes but that is how it is formatted right?

Comment: What date and time is `date` set to?

Comment: There is no date, because it should run everyday regardless of the date. Oh so I have to include date as well?

Comment: Read the javadoc for Timer.schedule. And every Date includes a date.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(date);` and it should become obvious why the timer triggers immediately.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void scheduler() throws ParseException {
    java.util.Timer _timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask tt;
    tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            foo();
        }
    };

  //Get the Date corresponding to 14:26:00 pm today.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 26);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Date time = calendar.getTime();
    _timer.schedule(tt,time);
}

public void foo(){
    System.out.println("Done");
}

**Note:** _timer.schedule(tt, time):- Schedules the specified task for execution at the specified time. If the time is in the past, the task is scheduled for immediate execution.
```

Comment: Explain why this solves the problem.  With sentences, not just code.